# Can't import styles using css-modules, webpack and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-style-loader, css-modules

I'm styling my react app. I'm using css-modules with webpack. Here's my config:

```
{ test: /\.css$/, loaders: ["style", "css?modules"] },
```

I styled my component, made a coffee and now it's not working. So I've got a stylesheet I want to use. I'm importing it with:

```
import styles from "./search.css";
```

But, when I break inside my component, `styles` is not defined. None of my styles are now being applied. Here's an example of how I'm using it:

```
// the chrome inspector only shows the first two styles, the last is not there
<div className={["col-md-2", "col-lg-1", styles.startTimes]}>
```

Why would `styles` be empty?

Answer (score 2):

Finally worked it out. This is not the right syntax:

```
<div className={["col-md-2", "col-lg-1", styles.startTimes]}>
```

You have you use [classNames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) and instead do:

```
<div className={cx("col-md-2", "col-lg-1", styles.startTimes)}>
```

You also need to only use class names in your CSS. If you style tag names directly (`h1`, etc) these are not applied locally.